# Position div elements to stick to the left & right of another div element?

Tags: javascript, css, html

How can I style two div elements so that they stick to the left & right of another div element like in the following example?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">Left.</div>
    <div id="box">This is a box.</div>
    <div id="right">Right.</div>
</div>
```

---

```
+#container--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                            |
|                                                            |
|        +#left---+#box-------------------+#right--+         |
|        |        |                       |        |         |
|        |        |                       |        |         |
|        |        |                       |        |         |
|        |  Left. |     This is a box.    | Right. |         |
|        |        |                       |        |         |
|        |        |                       |        |         |                                                            
|        +--------+-----------------------+--------+         |
|                                                            |
|                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I can see more like a `table` than `div` that you can use here

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jHs2b/

Answer (score 2):

```
#left{
    float: left;
}

#right{
   float: right;
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/rmz66/

Answer (score 1):

```
#container{
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
}
#left, #box, #right{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#left, #right{
    width: 200px;
}
#box{
    width: 500px;
}
```

Get rid of margins, paddings and etc, so you can maximise `#box`, and `#left`, `#right`

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {position:relative;}
#left, #right {position:absolute;}
#right {right:0;}
#box {width:XXX;margin:0 auto;}
```

Specify your box width and also a height if you don't have any content yet.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to put a `div` (let's call it "parent") around your three `div`. You center `#parent` inside your `#container` then you put `#box`, `#left` and `#right` in `float: left`. This should work.

A `table` or a list will work too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container" style="padding: 50px;border:1px solid gray">
    <div id="left" style="padding: 10px;float:left;border:1px solid green">Left.</div>
    <div id="box" style="padding: 10px;float:left;border: 1px solid red">This is a box.</div>
    <div id="right" style="padding: 10px;float:left;border:1px solid blue;">Right.</div>
</div>
```